# Order of classes matters when using variables from each other

Tags: python, class, variables

I am new to Python and didn't find an answer to the following problem:
I have two classes and want them to use variables from each other. Is there a simple way to do this because if I do it like this class a does not know that class b exists.

```
class a:
    y=1
    print(b.x)

class b:
    x=1
    print(a.y)
```

And how do I use overwrite the variables, the following code does not work:

```
class a:
    y=b.x

class b:
    x=1
```

Comment: You can use variable from the other class, but the way you used `print` is wrong. The class does not directly handle `print`, put it inside a function and then call that function instead.

Comment: How do I use variables from other classes? I am getting the NameError: name 'b' is not defined

Comment: In your latter case, define `b` first.

Comment: You're not really using classes in an effective manner (i.e. as though they were variables holding a single values). Generally speaking they should be thought-of and used as code templates without specific values assigned to as class attributes, but the instances of them using the `self` argument passed to all methods of the class.

Comment: But if I had 3 classes with different variables lets say Class A has variable a, Class B has variable b and Class C has variable c. Now I want to put a into B, b into C and C into a there would be no possibility?

Answer (score 2):

You are executing `print` as part of the class definition. It executes as soon as python sees that line of code, before it's read the part about `class b`.

Instead, use functions inside the classes to execute code *after* the classes have been defined:

```
class a:
    y=1
    def go():
        print(b.x)

class b:
    x=1
    def go():
        print(a.y)

a.go()
b.go()
```

Answer (score 1):

As I said in a comment, your code isn't making effective use of classes. Here's what I think would be better approach that offers more flexibility in working around the circular reference issue.

First the `class` definitions (which follow the [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) naming convention guidelines):

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, value, linked_value=None):
        self.y = value
        if isinstance(linked_value, B):
            self.linked_value = linked_value.x

    def print_linked_value(self):
        print(self.linked_value)


class B:
    def __init__(self, value, linked_value=None):
        self.x = value
        if isinstance(linked_value, A):
            self.linked_value = linked_value.y

    def print_linked_value(self):
        print(self.linked_value)
```

Definitions like that provide two ways to set up the circular references:

1. By creating them separately, then explicitly linking them:

   ```
   # First create instances of each class.
   a = A(1)
   b = B(42)

   # Then link them.
   a.linked_value = b.x
   b.linked_value = a.y

   a.print_linked_value()  # -> 42
   b.print_linked_value()  # -> 1
   ```
2. *OR* by creating the first one without a linked value and leaving only the second needing to be linked manually.

   ```
   # First create instances of each class, but link the second to the first
   # when it's created.
   a = A(1)
   b = B(42, a)  # Create and link to first.

   # Then link the first to the second to complete the circular references.
   a.linked_value = b.x

   # Same result.
   a.print_linked_value()  # -> 42
   b.print_linked_value()  # -> 1
   ```

**Final note**: Another, more advanced alternative that can also be applied in situations like this by using the built-in [`property()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#property) function as a decorator to create ["descriptors"](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-howto-guide). Here's [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44342705/355230) to a somewhat related question that illustrating its use.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
class A:
    y = 1
    def foo(self):
        print B.x

class B:
    x = 1
    def bar(self):
        print A.y

>>> A().foo()
2
>>> B().bar()
1
```

Use 'print' in some function definition.