# Issue with class declaration in python. Two classes with fields of each other

Tags: python, class

My code is something like this:

```
class className1:
    fieldClassName2 = className2()

class className2:
    fieldClassName1 = className1()
```

and i have NameError: name 'className2' is not defined.
I don't know if there is a declaration in python like in c++, and you can call classes in any order. Please help me...

full code:

```
    class Speciality(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    subject1 = models.ManyToManyField(Subject, verbose_name='Перший предмет', related_name='+')
    subject2 = models.ManyToManyField(Subject, verbose_name='Другий предмет', related_name='+')
    subject3 = models.ManyToManyField(Subject, verbose_name='Третій предмет', related_name='+')
    coefficient1 = models.FloatField()
    coefficient2 = models.FloatField()
    coefficient3 = models.FloatField()
    coefficient4 = models.FloatField()
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    budget_amount = models.IntegerField()
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, verbose_name='Факультет', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    code = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    abit = models.ManyToManyField(AdmissionList, verbose_name='Заявки', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.code)

# there some another models

class AdmissionList(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='Абітурієнт', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    speciality = models.ForeignKey(Speciality, verbose_name='Спеціальність', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    firstRate = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    secondRate = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    thirdRate = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    avgRate = models.FloatField(default=0)
    summaryRate = models.FloatField(default=0)
    is_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.full_name
```

field Speciality.abit is calls AdmissionList and field AdmissionList.speciality calls Speciality.

Comment: Can we see the code that uses these classes?

Comment: You should put these two fields in the `__init__` definition body instead of the class definition body.

Comment: class 1 instantiates class2, which instantiates class 1 which instantiates class 2... that looks problematic

Comment: `class` statements are executed in order; `className2` hasn't been defined yet when the `class` statement defining `className1` tries to use it.

Comment: They are *definitions*, not declarations.

Comment: What library or framework are you using? I vaguely remember seeing something in SQLAlchemy(?) which let you define keys in one class from another, avoiding this kind of circular reference. Maybe something similar exists in yours.

Comment: @chepner django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i avoid that problem by adding quotes into class call

```
abit = models.ManyToManyField(AdmissionList, verbose_name='Заявки', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

```
abit = models.ManyToManyField('AdmissionList', verbose_name='Заявки', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 2):

you could try something like this:

```
class className2:
    def __init__(self, fieldClassName1=False):
        self.fieldClassName1 = fieldClassName1

class className1:
    fieldClassName2 = className2()


var1 = className1()
var2 = className2(var1)


print(type(var2.fieldClassName1))
```

It distorts the current structure of your code, but it avoids circular dependency

Answer (score 0):

Python is an interpreted language, contrary to C++, which is a compiled language. Therefore, in Python, contrary to C++, the interpreter reads your code line by line. That is why when it gets to the first class definition, it doesn't know className2.

What you want to do is called a circular dependency. A similar problem has been described in this question :
[Circular dependency between python classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23026530/circular-dependency-between-python-classes)

If we adapt the solution to your problem, the result would be :

```
class className1:
    pass

class className2:
    pass

className1.fieldClassName2 = className2()
className2.fieldClassName1 = className1()
```

Comment: Django is not allow that solution.